# Custom post type and body_class: Remove "blog" class

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, css, customization

I am using `body_class();` to style different sections of a wordpress site by their body class. Page styles descend from `.page-template`, blog styles descend from `.single-post` and/or `.blog` etc.

I have created a custom post type "Products" for the products section of the site and want to style this section specifically using it's body class, but unfortunately `body_class();` is also giving the custom post type single pages the class `.blog` which is making many of the blog styles override the product styles- very frustrating.

Is there a way to take the "blog" class away for my custom post type single pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `body_class` filter to check if you are on your custom post type, and if so then just remove the `blog` class like this:

```
 function remove_blog_from_cpt_classes($classes, $class){
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type != "products"){
        return $classes;
    }else{
        foreach($classes as &$str){
            if(strpos($str, "blog") > -1){
                $str = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter("body_class", "remove_blog_from_cpt_classes", 10, 2);
```

Hope this helps